# MVC tic-tac-toe game

Tags: java, model-view-controller, observer-pattern, tic-tac-toe

I'm currently working at a project for school. We should refactor a Tic Tac Toe game written in Java, to something that works better. With the given code is a huge problem, the user interface isn't working well.

The problem is that the game isn't informed about the views of the two players. So, I should implement the observer pattern.

http://www.imgdumper.nl/uploads6/50a794d4ea6ba/50a794d4e2d9f-now.jpg

This image is the UML of the given code.

To make it work like a real game, I assume I would create a structure as following:

http://www.imgdumper.nl/uploads6/50a7953c6c6b3/50a7953c64186-new.jpg

Okay, I think that's right. But the aim of this project is to refactor it to the MVC pattern. In a presentation provided by school, I've found this scheme:
(see comment for url)

But I've no damn idea how I can refactor the code to something that meets the requirements of the MVC pattern. It would be nice if someone could explain me how I should do this. Like, what is the model, the contoller and the view?

Comment: http://www.imgdumper.nl/uploads6/50a798500a830/50a79850007fd-mvc.jpg

Answer (score 1):

I would apply the MVC pattern close to the current View layer of the application.  Essentially MVC can sit on top of current non-UI game logic and that logic can be encapsulated in a [Service Layer](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/serviceLayer.html).

`Model` is:

- SingleSquareState (X,O or NULL)
- GameBoard  (9 to 3n in size)
- Player

`View` displays the board -- it essentially "is" the board and has 9 (or sizeOf(GameBoard)) squares that can be turned X, O or NULL -- perhaps an array will do here.  Avoid putting much logic here, leave that to the controller.  The controller tells the view what to do.

`Controller` tells the Service (below) what move a player is making.  Then it receives an updated GameState from the service and tells the view(s) how to display it.

`Service` (aka GameState) keeps track of the game state across all players.  It may have a method called Move that the Controller can call.  The service validates whether that movie is legal by evaluating the gamestate, etc.  Then the service returns an updated state to the controller.

Comment: Okay, I will try to create a new UML based on you comment. But I'm believing I won't need Player. I think so because it is not required to play the game on different computers. The aim is, you launch the game on a computer, and you and your friend just play the game. (information like name etc is not required)